# Android Text & ImageView

Tags: android, textview, android-imageview

I know this question has been asked so many times but solution is not working for me. My `TextView` and `ImageView` are not clickable.

**Java:**

```
 public class temples extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temples);

        ImageView img_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
        img_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(temples.this, kaal_bhairav_info.class));
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**XML:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_temples" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/kaal_bhairav"

        android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
My logcat is not showing any error but nothing happens when image is clicked.
Same case with `TextView` also.
```

If I don't set `onClickListener` and write method (also setting android:onclick in xml)

Then get error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method perform
>   action(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick
>   attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'text_view'

I'm using android studio and testing on lollipop. I'm stuck.Please help.

Comment: Where is the `action(View)` method in your class? Or where are you calling it in your XML?

Comment: Is there not maybe another layout that might be over the ImageView. Would it be possible to post the entire XML layout?

Comment: Could you show more code for let us help you, please?

Comment: If you want to use android:onclick in xml then the method has to be defined in the activity. Could you also post all the full xml for the view containing the imageview and textview. The problem could be in a parent view of your imageview.

Comment: Have you tried pressing Alt+Enter in `onClick` attribute of XML... Where did it suggest to create method ?